# Powershell - difference between "-" (dash) and "." (hyphen)

Tags: powershell

I am a C# programmer, and I have been learning powershell haphazardly (as needed) off and on. I have a couple of (hopefully) quick questions about the difference between using a dot and a hyphen in powershell.

For example, in the case of an array.

```
$arr = @("sam", "mitch", "stan") #create array
$arr.Contains("sam") #contains, apparently .NET?
$arr -contains "sam" #contains, apparently PS?
```

What is the difference between the "contains" calls?

What causes the .Contains() to be available? I know a .NET array has a .Contains method ... is this the same thing? Is it available because of the public accessor? Does PS just "know" what a .NET array is?

What causes the -contains notation to be available?

Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Thanks!

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx

Comment: Oh it's just an operator?? I guess that explains it!

Comment: Indeed. And you're right on the money with the .Contains method.

Comment: Be careful when using `func(a,b,c)` syntax to call a function in Powershell: https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/powershell-function-declaration-pitfall

Comment: "*Does PS just 'know' what a .Net array is*" - PS arrays *are* .Net arrays. `@(1,2,3).GetType()` -> `Object[], basetype System.Array`. But PowerShell has an [Adapted Type System (ATS) layer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2011/11/22/psobject-and-the-adapted-and-extended-type-systems-ats-and-ets/) where it can wrap and extend underlying objects with more convenient properties and methods. `@(1,2,3) | get-member -view adapted` suggests all the methods on an array have a later of PS adapting indirection over the .Net methods, for .. I don't know what reasons (case insensitivity?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from the C# world, let's pretend for a moment that `Contains()` is just an extension method on `Enumerable`... something [not far from the truth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

With that in mind, it's important to remember that calling `arr.Contains( ... )` in C# is syntactic sugar. The **real** syntax is actually `Enumerable.Contains(arr, ... )`.

Something similar is going on here. In PowerShell, you have things called [**`Cmdlets`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714395(v=vs.85).aspx). Cmdlets make up the bulk of the language's idiomatic API. It's very common for Cmdlets to have a number of optional arguments that determine what the Cmdlet actually does. The syntax for Cmdlet arguments looks like this:

```
 CmdletName -argumentname "optional argument parameter"
```

Now, I know this code (`$arr -contains "sam"`) doesn't exactly follow that pattern, but it's a better way to understand what powershell is doing. As far as powershell goes, the most idiomatic code for someone who learned it first would be to use the "native" cmdlet argument-style syntax:

```
$arr -contains "sam"
```

I put native in scare quotes here, becuase Powershell ultimately relies a great deal on .Net, and likely it's calling the exact same .Net `Contains()` method in much the same way that .Net would: lookup the `$arr` object reference to resolve and call it's `Contains()` function. It may even be that, when it comes down to it, `$arr.Contains("sam")` is the more direct path for the Powershell execution environment to produce the desired function call. However, when in Rome... I try to use the natural powershell syntax when possible, even if, as a fellow C# user, the other way feels much more natural to me and I don't always succeed.

That said, your comment to the question that `-contains` is operator is also very close. Take a look at the other powershell equality operators: `-eq`, `-ne`, -`lt`, `-gt`, `-le`, `-ge`, `-like`, etc. To help them feel more familiar, let's go back to C#, and look at how C# really does equality; it's **not** `==`. Rather, C#'s most significant equality operator is often `obj.Equals()`. Suddenly, that doesn't feel so different from `obj.Contains()` any more.

Comment: "*It may even be that, when it comes down to it, $arr.Contains("sam") is the more direct path for the Powershell execution environment to produce the desired function call*" - They are not exactly the same thing; `@('A','B','C') -contains 'b'` is True, `@('A','B','C').Contains('b')` is False. PowerShell operators do something to make them case insensitive by default.

Comment: *"your comment to the question that -contains is operator is also very close"* - What? It's not close, *it's the truth*

Comment: It is `Enumerable.Contains(arr, ... )` not `IEnumerable.Contains(arr, ... )`. Also `$arr.Contains("sam")` in PowerShell would call `IList.Contains`: `((IList)arr).Contains("sam")`, not the extension method `Enumerable.Contains`.